# Is it possible to export/import a single site from MSM?

Tags: channel-entries, multi-site-manager, multiple-sites

I've got a Multiple Site Manager set up with 3 different sites. I'm wondering if it is possible to export all EE content/channels/data from one of the sites, and import that same site data into another Multiple Site Manager instance. Is this easily accomplished, or will it involve dark SQL magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: no, nothing easy about this. All the data is stored in the same database tables using database-specific channels IDs, field IDs, entry IDs, etc, etc - which will almost for sure conflict with existing channels, fields, and entries in your destination database.

It's doable, but it's part-manual, part-automated, and requires a huge amount of analysis of both databases in order to figure out how you need to alter existing records so they don't conflict.